# Why is 'this' always a Window in a prototype for Javascript Classes

Tags: javascript, object, window, this, prototype-programming

Here is the code

```
function Person(name, age, weight) {
    this._name = name;
    this._weight = weight;
    this._age = age;
}

Person.prototype = {
    Anatomy: {
        Weight: this._weight,
        Height: (function () {
            //calculate height from age and weight
        })
    }
}
```

i expected `Anatomy.weight` to be 60 when i ran this code:

```
var x = new Person('jack',24,60);
console.dir(x.Anatomy);
```

To my surprise it was undefined. On inspection it seemed that `this` was referring to global object window. Now what has happened here :(
I expected `this._weight` to refer Person objects weight, otherwise from rough calculation, this should have at the least referred to Anatomy since it is a object. Could someone clarify the doubt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't to that. `this` is only available in functions. Where you used it, it refers to the global object. A possible solution would be this:

```
function Anatomy(weight) {
    this.Weight = weight;
    this.Height = [...];
}

function Person(name, age, weight) {
    this._name = name;
    this._weight = weight;
    this._age = age;
    this.Anatomy = new Anatomy(this._weight);
}
```

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it's the best that I can think of right now.

Comment: Obviously understood that can't be done from what i explained above. So what should be done? this isn't the best of answer to be voted for

Comment: @Deeptechtons, I edited the answer to provide an alternative. See here also a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C3puH/

Answer (score 1):

`this` changes based on scope, and scope is only effected by functions.  Thus, since Person.prototype is just an object that is not in a function, `this` refers to the global object, which in browsers tends to be `window`.

Edit: example fix

```
function Person(name, age, weight) {
    this._name = name;
    this._weight = weight;
    this._age = age;
    this.Anatomy: {
        Weight: this._weight,
        Height: (function () {
            //calculate height from age and weight
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: so what do you suggest to do with person class to get the result i want

Comment: @Deeptechtons I'm not sure why you're adding functions to the prototype, since you're going to be creating objects with new anyway.  Will add example above.

Comment: i don't understand, prototypes are designed for this purpose right?? am i missing something

Comment: @Deeptechtons I can't tell what your purpose is, or how it relates to prototypes.  Perhaps you can be more clear about what you are trying to do and how it requires modifying the prototype property directly?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with prototypes.

When you work in browser, your context (`this`) is set to `window` object. This allows you to call `setTimeout` and `alert` et al. as if they were global functions. I.e. any your script is a method of global `window` object.

This is not true in other Javascript hosts, e.g. in node.js.

Comment: why is this, all have the same answers!! so what should i do for the thing to work as i expected wrap inside closure